# Calculated field on mail

Tags: civimember

I want to add some information on a mail which is in fact calculated based on existing fields. More specifically, I want to send a mail to all members with an expired membership. In the mail I want to add (what we call in Belgium) a structured message which is in my case "membershipID & (membershipID mod 97)". What is the best way to accomplish this?

Answer (score 1):

You could create a custom token to do the calculation and use the token in your mail.  See eg https://wiki.civicrm.org/confluence/display/CRMDOC/Customized+%28and+Custom%29+Tokens